# How do I define a dependency on an executable in Haskell Stack?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

In a default configuration created with `stack new`, the project structure is something like this:

```
# package.yaml
name: my-cool-app

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  my-cool-app-exe:
    source-dirs: app

tests:
  my-cool-app-tests:
    source-dirs: test
    dependencies:
      - my-cool-app # refers to the library
```

How do I define a dependency on the executable, so that my test project can include tests of code that resides in `./app`?

Comment: I don't think you can. The usual way to go is to have almost all the code in a library, and then have a very-very thin wrapper in the executable.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I was afraid so, but since I think it _should_ be possible I had to ask :)