# Haskell Stack: trying to rebuild the executable in stack test

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am using Haskell and Stack, and I have the following project:

```
name:                foo

dependencies:
- base

library:
  source-dirs: src

executables:
  foo:
    source-dirs:      app
    main:             Main.hs
    dependencies:
    - foo

tests:
  end-to-end:
    main:                Spec.hs
    source-dirs:         test/end-to-end
    dependencies:
    - foo
    # foo:exe:foo should also be a dependency
    - hspec
    - process
```

The app is a thin wrapper around the library, but I would like to test it, mostly to make sure that the CLI works as intended.

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58772569/how-do-i-define-a-dependency-on-an-executable-in-haskell-stack), it seems that I cannot add `foo:exe:foo` as a dependency of `end-to-end`.

To circumvent this, I tried to invoke a subprocess in `test/end-to-end/Spec.hs` to (re)build `foo:exe:foo`:

```
build :: IO ()
build = void (readCreateProcess (shell "stack build foo:exe:foo") "")

main :: IO ()
main = do
  build
  hspec ...
```

However, this hangs forever with the message `foo> blocking for directory lock on .stack-work/dist/x86_64-linux-tinfo6/Cabal-3.2.1.0/build-lock`

Do you please have any idea what the problem is and what I am doing wrong?

I am aware that I could have another tool to build and run the end-to-end tests, but that would mean using Stack for all unit tests, and another tool for the end-to-end tests, which would be less convenient than typing `stack test` and be able run all my tests (unit and end-to-end).

Comment: The proper way to define such a dependency in `Cabal` is via the [`build-tool-depends` field](https://cabal.readthedocs.io/en/3.8/cabal-package.html#pkg-field-build-tool-depends). Unfortunately stack doesn't handle these dependencies quite correctly: https://github.com/commercialhaskell/stack/issues/5342. The workaround is to include the executable in the test targets, e.g. `stack test foo:end-to-end foo:exe:foo`.

Comment: @sjakobi: Thank you very much for your answer! However, do you also know why I cannot invoke `stack build foo:exe:foo` within `stack test`?

Comment: I guess the `stack test` process is holding the build lock. `stack test` is just a shortcut for `stack build --test`.